# Prevent the JVM from terminating when executing gradle run

Tags: java, gradle, vert.x

[image: code to prevent JVM exit]

In the above code, I've commented the line which *should* be preventing the JVM from exiting.
However, when I execute this program using the command `gradle run`, the code doesn't do what I expect it to.

What do I need to do to accomplish this?

Pictured below are the results of the `gradle run` command:

[image: gradle run command results]

Comment: I suggest you turn on gradle debug or info level to see more details about what is causing the behaviour. 
An idea is that the daemon is turned on, which would cause stdin to be unavailable.

Answer (score 0):

That is because `gradle run` essentially executes a [JavaExec](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.JavaExec.html) task which executes the java process in a child process.

If you see the documentation of JavaExec task

> standardInput :    The standard input stream for the process executing the command. The stream is closed after the process completes. Defaults to an empty stream.

Try providing `System.in` as the standardInput and re run the gradle run task.